# How do you convert a javascript array to a formatted JSON String

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Lets say I have an object that looks like this:

```
var test = {
    jsonString: {
        groups: ['1','2','3','4','5']
    }

}
```

How would I get it to look like a json string like this?

```
var test = {
    jsonString: "{\"groups\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\"]}"
  }
```

I am a little lost on how to do this. and I do not **think** that `JSON.stringify(test.jsonString)` would do the exact trick I need, but I could just be doing it wrong. Any help or any direction on where to look would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: yes, that's exactly what it is. Did you try it?

Comment: I did and it didn't work.. maybe I had somewthing wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Use `JSON.stringify`. Do not try to serialize on your own

Comment: Guys it is official, I am an idiot. It works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what you need to do. Then assign it back to the property.

```js
var test = {
    jsonString: {
        groups: ['1','2','3','4','5']
    }
}

test.jsonString = JSON.stringify(test.jsonString);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Lol thanks. It worked as is. I had an extra step in the IOT I am using that was breaking the json, not JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

Using `JSON.stringify()` gives you the exact output you're looking for.

Here's a demo on jsbin: https://jsbin.com/kegigusuyo/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Post your code here as a stack snippet, not just at jsbin.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the JSON.stringify method

```
var test = {
   jsonString: {
       groups: ['1','2','3','4','5']
   }
}

var test2 = JSON.stringify(test.jsonString);
```

Output:

```
"{"groups":["1","2","3","4","5"]}"
```

[Find more about JSON Stringify here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)